# Identify Temporal Table in Teradata Database

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, temporal-tables, teradatasql

Is there a SQL query which can fetch the list of all Temporal Table from Teradata Database?

Is there any special Column for Temporal Tables which identifies them of which type of Temporal Table it is?

Answer (score 2):

There is a TemporalProperty column in dbc.tablesv.

```
SELECT * FROM dbc.TablesV WHERE TemporalProperty <> 'N'
```

TemporalProperty values (thanks @Dnoeth):

```
V: ValidTime
T: TransactionTime
B: BiTemporal
N: Not Temporal
```